# Append table row with ajax response data

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm doing an ajax call in my mvc app and then wanting to add rows to an existing table. I have attached the relevant code below.
I have a table of catalog items and when the user clicks on a row I perform an ajax call which is successful and does return the expected data.

When I loop through the data, I see the table rows being created, but the .append() does not actually append the new row to the #tblApplications table.

What am I doing wrong with my code below?

```
<table id="tblApplications">
<tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Partnumber)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.VehicleYear)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Make)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ModelDescription)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EngineDescription)

    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Parttype)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Notes)
    </th>
</tr>
```

```
<script>
     jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.toggle').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $cur = $(this).closest('tr').next('.view-details').stop().toggle();
        $('.view-details').not($cur).stop().hide();
        var partnum = $(this).closest('tr').find('.PartNumber').text().trim();
        $("#ApplicationPartNumber").val(partnum);

         $.ajax({
             url: "@Url.Action("GetApplications", "Admin")",
             data: { 'ApplicationPartNumber': partnum },
            success: function (response, status, xhr) {
                var apps = JSON.stringify(response);
                var trHTML = '';
                $.each(JSON.parse(apps), function (idx, obj) {

                  trHTML=  '<tr><td>' + obj.Partnumber + '</td><td>'
                        + obj.VehicleYear + "</td><td>"
                        + obj.Make + "</td><td>" 
                        + obj.ModelDescription + "</td><td>" 
                        + obj.EngineDescription + "</td><td>" 
                        + obj.Parttype + "</td><td>"
                        + obj.Notes + "</td></tr>";

                    $('#tblApplications').append(trHTML);

                }); 

           },
    });
    })
})
```

Comment: Doesn't make sense to stringify the response. Try adding `dataType:'json'` to `$.ajax` options and then just do `$.each(response...`. Beyond that .. the append process seems sound

Comment: I think I found the problem. The tblApplications is nested in another table when the row is clicked in that table the ajax is called to populate tblApplications. It is hidden with css. How do I overcome that issue? I understand about dataType:'json'. Thanks

Comment: Use `show()` on whatever parent is hidden

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks you! Have not done JavaScript in a while. That did the trick. Also, much cleaner using the dataType:'json' on the ajax call.